# Why doesn't swift allow for let-based decisions in ternaries?

Tags: swift

It's possible to do the following in Swift:

```
let params: String
if let aString = someOptionalString {
    params = "?someparam=\(aString)"
} else {
    params = ""
}
```

However it would be much more concise if I could write it like:

```
let params = let aString = someOptionalString ? "?someparam=\(aString)" : ""
```

Or

```
let params = case let aString = someOptionalString ? "?someparam=\(aString)" : ""
```

However this doesn't compile in any way I could think about. Is this possible? If not, why not? And is there a way to suggest it to be implemented or can I only try to first add this myself to the Swift project and then propose the change to the community?

Comment: "doesn't compile". With what error? Did you try wrapping the ternary in parenthesis? Also, it looks like your trying to refer to aString in its own definition. Why the nested `let`?

Comment: Yes, let me update the answer in a few minutes

Comment: You may use map instead of this `someOptionalString.map { "?someparam\($0)" } ?? ""`

Comment: You can do `let params = someOptionalString == nil ? "" : "?someparam=\(someOptionalString!)"`

Comment: Yeah but force unwrapping....I know it sounds a bit pedantic but it's a code smell and this is the only place I cannot get around it with the regular methods that prevent force unwrapping. I also have it set up as a rule for coding reviews and trying to figure out if I can lint against it.

Comment: Well, I believe you are doing it the wrong way anyway. Parameters are basically a key-value dictionary. So you could use `dict["someparam"] = aString`. That won't add a `nil` value. Generating the query then means to take all values, encode them to `key=\(encode(value))` and then join everything with `&` characters.

Comment: `Why doesn't swift allow for let-based decisions in ternaries?
` because `let params = let aString = someOptionalString ? "?someparam=\(aString)" : ""` and `let params = case let aString = someOptionalString ? "?someparam=\(aString)" : ""` are both garbled messes that nobody would want in this language.

Comment: @Sulthan it was a quickly hacked up example but this situation just pops up every now and then and I never felt like I had a solution for it that just felt good

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because mapping an optional is a much more sensible choice:

```
let params = someOptionalString.map{ "?someparam\($0)" } ?? ""
```

Comment: Thanks for answering the question behind the question. I had no idea map could be used that way.

Comment: @DepartamentoB Yep. There's `flatMap` too, which calls a given closure, and flattens 2 layers of optionalality into one

Comment: I just tried it in Swift 4 and it still worked the same. Could be confusing for people that expect strings to behave like collections of characters they can map over though....

Comment: @DepartamentoB Then those people should learn the difference between `Optional<String>` and `String` :)

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question as given, conditional `let` only applies in an `if` statement or similar branching construct, everywhere else it doesn't have a value.

Normally when you have a pattern like:

```
if let x = y {
    doSomething(x)
}
```

...what you're doing is declaring a new namespace context inheriting from the current one where `x` is defined; whether the code enters that context depends on whether the assigning expression evaluates to `nil`. Outside the block, `x` is not defined and it's an error to refer to it. If you like, think of it as a closure, something that might look like:

```
callIfNotNil(y, {x in doSomething(x)})
```

When you do a `let` otherwise, you are defining it in the current namespace, which means it can't *not* be defined on the other side of the ternary operator, so the best the compiler could give you is `String!` as a type, which would defer the nil check to runtime, largely defeating the point of using it.

In principle ternary could apply the same behaviour by defining an implicit block in the middle of the expression, but that's a recipe for confusion on the part of the programmer.

As for why `let x = true; let y = x ? 1 : 2` is valid but `let y = let x = true ? 1 : 2` isn't, there are some trivial precedence problems there, and with the `let` keyword being a compile-time feature not a runtime one it would be misleading to allow it mid-expression.